# Linq-to-SQL strange behaviour

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Assume two tables Groups and Users as follows

```
[Groups] ([Id] [int] NOT NULL, [Name] [nchar](50) NULL);
[Users] ([Id] [int] NOT NULL, [Name] [nchar](50) NULL, [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL);
FOREIGN KEY([GroupId]) REFERENCES [Groups] ([Id])
```

Where GroupId is a foreign key to Users.

Then I use Linq-to-SQL class designer to create pertinent classes and I add following class to the project

```
public partial class Group
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Id.GetHashCode());
    }

    public override bool Equals(object item)
    {
        if ((item == null) || (item is System.DBNull))
            return (false);
        else
        {
            var temp = item as Group;
            if (temp == null)
                return (false);
            else
                if (_Id.Equals(0))
                    return (_Name.Equals(temp.Name));
                else
                    return (_Id == temp.Id);
        }
    }

    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {
        var dc = new DB.DataContext();

        if (action == System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction.Insert)
            if (dc.Groups.Count(o => o.Name.Equals(_Name)) != 0)
                throw new Exception("Name Already Exist On Insert");

        if (action == System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction.Update)
            if (dc.Groups.Count(o => (!o.Id.Equals(_Id) && o.Name.Equals(_Name))) != 0)
                throw new Exception("Name Already Exist On Update");
    }
}

public partial class User
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Id.GetHashCode());
    }

    public override bool Equals(object item)
    {
        if ((item == null) || (item is System.DBNull))
            return (false);
        else
        {
            var temp = item as User;
            if (temp == null)
                return (false);
            else
                if (_Id.Equals(0))
                    return (_Name.Equals(temp.Name));
                else
                    return (_Id == temp.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public static DB.Group f1()
{
    DB.DataContext dc = new DB.DataContext();
    if (dc.Groups.Count() == 0)
    {
        DB.Group group = new DB.Group() { Name = "admins" };
        dc.Groups.InsertOnSubmit(group);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
    return dc.Groups.First();
}

public static void f2(DB.Group group, string name)
{
    DB.DataContext dc = new DB.DataContext();
    DB.User user = new DB.User() { Name = name, GroupId = group.Id, };
    dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}

public static void f3(DB.Group group, string name)
{
    DB.DataContext dc = new DB.DataContext();
    DB.User user = new DB.User() { Name = name, Group = group, };
    dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

now if I call

```
DB.Group group = f1();
f2(group, "john");
f2(group, "bob");
```

then everything goes fine but if I call

```
DB.Group group = f1();
f2(group, "john");
f3(group, "bob");
```

it throws an exception "Name Already Exist On Insert". In fact, OnValidate has been called and it detects duplicate names for group table. The strange behavior is that OnValidate is called when new user is going to be inserted into the table. What's going on? Have I made a mistake?

Comment: have you tried setting your Users.ID to primary key with auto increment ?

Comment: Yes, both `Group.ID` and `User.ID` are primary keys and `Identity` (or auto increment). I even tried it with both `Group.ID` and `User.ID` set to `uniqueidentifier` and their default values set to `NewID()`. but the result is the same as described.

Comment: i guess the problem isn't on your UserId dbType, i think that on your insert (f3) it tries to insert the group as well as the user, instead of simply adding a user with a group id (like f2).
I think you will have to select the group and then attach the user to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that, because you are creating a new DataContext in f3, it assumes that you want to insert group as a new record.

You can manually attach group to the new DataContext, so that it won't try to insert it.

```
public static void f3(DB.Group group, string name)
{
    DB.DataContext dc = new DB.DataContext();
    dc.Groups.Attach(group);
    DB.User user = new DB.User() { Name = name, Group = group, };
    dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Alternatively, you can create one DataContext, rather than creating a new one for each method.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer to have a better solution for that. In fact I decided to use Linq-to-SQL designer as ORM for a database with more than 100 tables and I've implemented a Repository Pattern. Now I have to modify Add method for most of Repository Classes. Isn't there any better solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Group = group,
```

In f3, you attached the instance of the group to the user.  Then you told the datacontext to insert the user.  Because there is group connected to the user, and the datacontext is not currently tracking that group, it assumes the group needs to be inserted as well.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in comment to @sgmoore answer attaching objects to datacontext does not sound to be a perfect solution. Is there any notification mechanism for datacontext to be notified when other instances are changed?

Comment: The behavior of datacontext is great when you want to insert/update a graph of instances with one call to submitchanges.  If you want to manage the instance tracking of one datacontext, use an overload of Attach for instances it should start tracking or an overload of Refresh of instances it is already tracking.